# Business Card Crop Marks for Printer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, print-production

Have a business card file created in AI. Printer is asking for crop marks and we are looking to have 1/4" rounded corners for the cards. How do I create crop marks or setup bleed for this? or is the setup for the 1/4" rounded corners the printers responsibility and I simply supply standard crop marks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you set up crops and bleeds like you would without rounded corners. Because all standard business cards are the same size, you ordinarily *don't* need to create any die lines or anything special. Most print providers, especially online print providers, have their own die for rounding corners of business cards since it's a common request.

**You customarily don't need to do *anything* special with the artwork and merely be certain to *specify rounded corners* when ordering the business card printing.**

---

For online printers, it's merely an option when ordering....

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]